# Minimizing an action that leads to a non-linear second order differential equation of the Emden-Fowler type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to solve the following problem inspired by physics:

I have a functional $S$ defined by
$$
S[f] = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dr
\left( \frac{f'(r)^2}{r^2}
 + \frac{f(r)^4}{r^6} \right)
$$
and I am looking for real functions $f(r)$ over the interval $r \in (0, \infty)$ that minimize $S$, with the boundary conditions:

- $f(0) = 0$,
- $f(\infty) = c$ for some constant $c \geq 0$.

The solution in the case $c = 0$ is simply $f(r) = 0$. When $c \neq 0$ the problem must have a solution but I am not able to make any progress:

- Numerically this is a boundary value problem and I don't know how to solve it efficiently. My attempt using a basic relaxation method does not seem to work.
- Analytically, using the variational principle, $f$ must satisfy a second-order differential equation that is of the Emden-Fowler type: defining $t = r^3$ and $f(r) = g(t)$, the functional can be rewritten
  $$
  S[g] = \frac{3}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dt
  \left( g'(t)^2
   + \frac{g(t)^4}{9 t^{8/3}} \right)
  $$
  and the variational principle give
  $$
  g''(t) = \frac{2}{9} \frac{g(t)^3}{t^{8/3}},
  $$
  but it does not seem to have closed-form solution
  (see *Polyanin, A. D.; Zaitsev, Valentin F.*, Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations., Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press. xxvi, 787 p. (2003). [ZBL1015.34001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1015.34001).).

Does anyone have a hint at how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I have no hint for this particular equation. But check $g(t)=it^{1/3}$

Comment: @Isham I didn't write it in the question, but it's true that there exists a particular complex solution. At the end of the day I'm interested in real functions, but do you think something can be gained from complexifying the problem?

Comment: I don't know I was just playing with the equation and somme particular polynomials. Maybe there is a substitution that allow to get rid of the $t^{3/8}$ factor

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that my question is not a very interesting one. It turns out that the problem does not admit non-trivial solutions.

To see this, split the integral into two pieces:
$$
S[f] = S_1[f] + S_2[f]
\quad \text{where} \quad
S_1[f] = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dr \, \frac{f'(r)^2}{r^2}
\quad \text{and} \quad
S_2[f] = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dr \, \frac{f(r)^4}{r^6}
$$
Each piece is separately non-negative,
$S_1[f] \geq 0$ and $S_2[f] \geq 0$.

Now assume that we found a solution $f(r)$ minimizing $S[f]$, and define $f_\lambda(r) = f(\lambda r)$. Then we have
$$
S[f_\lambda] = \lambda^3 S_1[f] + \lambda^5 S_2[f]
$$
This implies 
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda}S[f_\lambda] \Big|_{\lambda = 1}
= 3 S_1[f] + 5 S_2[f] \geq 0
$$
By assumption that $f$ is a function minimizing $S[f]$, the derivative must be zero  at $\lambda = 1$. This means that both $S_1[f] = 0$ and $S_2[f] = 0$, which is only satisfied by the trivial solution $f = 0$.

(Note that this proof is a variant of "[Derrick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derrick%27s_theorem)")

Comment: You're making things too complicated. Note that an integral is equal to zero iff the integrand is identically zero (when the integrand is continuous). As $ f $ is differentiable, it is continuous, and thus $ S _ 2 $ takes it minimum value only when $ f = 0 $ (which in turn makes the value of $ S _ 1 $ and thus $ S $ also equal to their minimum value $ 0 $), and you're done.